# Pascal Считывание из файла количества элементов массива

Tags: freepascal

Нужно:
- считать из первой строки текстового файла количество контрольных тестов (например - 2);
- со второй - количество элементов массива (например - 5);
- с третьей - сам массив (например - 1 2 3 4 5);
- с четвёртой - снова кол-во элементов массива (например - 10);
- с пятой - снова массив (например - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).
После определённых операций с массивам вывести преобразованные массивы в файл, например:

5

5 4 3 2 1

10

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

(где: 5 и 10 - количество элементов для каждого теста).

С массивом - проблем нет! Как считать первые две переменные (кол-во тестов и элементов) и состыковать с программой так - чтобы программа работала независимо от количества контрольных тестов и элементов?

Comment: А зачем там это количество? Ведь и без него видно, что 5. И без 10 видно, что 10

Comment: Видимо N для того, чтобы указать - из скольких элементов будет формироваться массив (например a:array[1..N] of integer) при описании переменных в программе. Вот я как-раз и не могу связать N из файла с N в описании массива в Var

Comment: В паскале вроде константа в размерности массива? т.е. её никак не задать через переменную. Значит надо завести массив с запасом, но использовать индексы только до переменной n, считанной из файла. Но в фрипаскале можно задать размер динамически. `a : array of integer; ... SetLength(a, n); ....`

Comment: Я в курсе! Вот только константу не получается считать из файла...

Comment: Сейчас попробую...

Comment: На то она и константа, что задаётся раз и навсегда. причём в программе, а не каком-то там файле. Кстати индексы динамического массива начинается с нуля. 0. a[0], a[1], ... a[n-1] последний

Comment: Вот ссылка на файл с кодом: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5li8umyXUzzcWRmSFFrV3dwVXc на условие: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5li8umyXUzzaFFOaE1pWEpDSmM и на входной файл: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5li8umyXUzzNTFXdUdDMmlQWkE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В задании что сказано? В массиве и N (1 <= N <= 10000) чисел. Значит смело пишем

```
var a: array [1..10000] of integer;
```

Все 10000 не обязательно понадобятся. Сколько нужно будет указывать переменная n. Там ещё какое-то количество тестов будет. Пусть это будет переменная t;

```
    n: integer;
    t: integer;

begin

    ...

    ReadLn(f1, t); // прочитали количество тестов
    for i : = 1 to t do begin // цикл по количеству тестов

        Readln(f1, n); // прочитать количество элементов очередного массива

        for i := 1 to n do Read(f1, a[i]); // вычитываем n элементов
        ReadLn(f1); // перейти на следующую строку.

        for i := 1 to n do begin // это цикл обработки массива. n элементов.
           ...
        end;

    end;

    ...

end.
```

`ReadLn(f1)` - перейти на следующую строку.
`ReadLn(f1, n)` - считать из файла число и перейти на следующую строку.
`for i := 1 to n do` - цикл от единицы до числа, указанного в переменной n вместо фискированной 10 или 10000.

А входной файл совершенно не соответствует условиям задачи

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Входной файл был просто временным (без заданий на повтор и количества элементов), чтобы проверить работу основного кода.